# Dynamic multidimensional array in twig

Tags: arrays, twig

I have an array, but I need to restructure it. I can only do this in twig.

Original array element looks like `$arr[0]`:

```
"_id" => array:3 [
"cityName" => "someCityName"
"id" => 111
"className" => "someClassName"
  ]
"count" => 85
```

my result array element should look like $arr[0]:

```
"someCityName" => [
    12 => [
        "someClassName" => 32,
        "someOtherClassName" => 44
    ]
]
```

in php I would just do

```
$arr[$cityName][$id][$className] = $count;
```

And this would work, but this must be done in twig.

I was hoping to use twig merge, but when I try doing

```
{% for infoArr in result %}
{% set cityName = infoArr['_id']['cityName'] %}
{% set id = infoArr['_id']['id'] %}
{% set class = infoArr['_id']['className'] %}
{% set countCity.cityName = countCity.cityName|merge({(id):([])}) %}
```

{% endfor %}

or

```
{% set countCity[cityName] = countCity[cityName]|merge({(id):([])}) %}
```

> the error is Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of
>   statement block" expected)

.

How should this be done in twig correctly?

Comment: Don't do this in twig. You would need to reconstruct every part of the multi dimensional array and merge it right back. Write a filter/function to modify the array

Comment: you can show the reconstruction process?

Comment: You want a new array actually right?

Comment: I need an array with different structure, like I described. If it is new or not I do not care, but I suppose it should be new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do something like this in `twig`, which I'm **not** encouraging,  you need to reconstruct every part of the array. Also note you can't use `merge` with numeric indeces, otherwise the data will be appended, not overwritten. More information on this issue [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/789)

```
$data = [
    'data' => [
        [
            '_id' => [
                'cityName'  => 'foo',
                'className' => 'alpha',
                'id'        => 42,
            ],
            'count' => 40,
        ],
        [
            '_id' => [
                'cityName'  => 'bar',
                'className' => 'alpha',
                'id'        => 55,
            ],
            'count' => 123,
        ],
        [
            '_id' => [
                'cityName'  => 'foo',
                'className' => 'beta',
                'id'        => 42,
            ],
            'count' => 99,
        ],
    ],
];
```

---

```
{% set output = {} %}

{% for raw in data %}
    {% if not attribute(output, raw._id.cityName) is defined %}
        {% set output = output|merge({ (raw._id.cityName) : {}, }) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if not attribute(output[raw._id.cityName], 'id_'~raw._id.id) is defined %}
        {% set output = output|merge({(raw._id.cityName) : output[raw._id.cityName] | merge({('id_'~raw._id.id):[], }) }) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% set output = output|merge({(raw._id.cityName) : output[raw._id.cityName] | merge({('id_'~raw._id.id): output[raw._id.cityName]['id_'~raw._id.id]|merge({(raw._id.className): raw.count}), }) }) %}
{% endfor %}


{{ output.foo.id_42.alpha }} {# output: 40 #}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ysqkxs)