# twig merge error Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "["

Tags: php, symfony, merge, twig

My goal is having a string like "name: smoothie, ingredients: milk, orange, category: vegan" (there can be a lot option: value or option: value, value, value... pairs) to produce an array like the following

```
[
  {
     option: 'name',
     value: ['smoothie']
  },
  {
     option: 'ingredients',
     value: ['milk', 'orange']
  },
  {
     option: 'category',
     value: ['vegan']
  }
]
```

I thought something like the following would work but it produces the following error and i can't understand why.
The problem is in the line where i try to add a value to the existing options[last_ok_index].value array

```
{% set options[last_ok_index].value = options[last_ok_index].value|merge( [ x[0] ] ) %}
```

Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block" expected).

```
{% set product = "name: smoothie, ingredients: milk, orange" %}
{% set options = [] %}
{% set last_ok_index = 0 %}
{% for item in product|split(',') %}
    {% set x = item|split(': ') %}
    {% if x|length == 2 %}
        {% set options = options|merge( [ { option: x[0], value: [x[1]] } ] ) %}
        {% set last_ok_index = loop.index - 1 %}
    {% else %}
        {% set options[last_ok_index].value = options[last_ok_index].value|merge( [ x[0] ] ) %}
    {% endif%}
{% endfor %}

{# print result #}
{% for item in options %}
    {{item.option }}
    {% for inner_item in item.value %}
        {{"-" ~ inner_item}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in a template instead of a controller or straight PHP?

Comment: i'm not supposed to touch any of the controllers code...and i believe it is possible in twig somehow

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not reduce the code step by step to spot the problem?

Comment: the problem is in line 
{% set options[last_ok_index].value = options[last_ok_index].value|merge( [ x[0] ] ) %}
so it is when i try to add a value in the existing options[last_ok_index].value array

Comment: Have you considered writing a TwigExtension that handles parsing the string and returning the array? That way you can use PHP without needing to modify any existing code, e.g. in controllers. You could take this as a template: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504988/1166880

Comment: The problem already starts at your first `split`, your expected output is `smoothie` and `ingredients`, while the actual result will be `smoothie`, `ingredients`,  `orange`

Comment: @DarkBee run it and remove the problematic line to check...If i could add to the array the value i'm trying to add it would be ok

Comment: I know that as well, merging a multidimensional array in `twig` is not as easy as you've tried in your snippet, you'd need to merge every part of the array as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461972/dynamic-multidimensional-array-in-twig). Anyway in your case it's not required as seen in my answer below

Comment: Why not write a TwigExtension that you could properly test and debug with common PHP tools? This would be way easier than relying on such hacks

Comment: @NicoHaase no clue, some people just want to do everything inside `twig`

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the suggestion in the comments by @dbrumann and use a `TwigExtension`.
However if you want to solve this in pure `twig`, then you are overcomplicating things.

First things first, the problem already starts at your first `split`, your expected output is `smoothie` and `ingredients`, while the actual result will be `smoothie`, `ingredients`, `orange`. You can fix this by passiung asecond argument to the `split` filter, which will limit the output.

`Split` uses the `PHP` function `explode` in the background. More on what the second parameters does you can find in the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/explode)

Now as I said you can simply your snippet by creating the "item" in two parts rather than one part

```html
{% set product = "name: smoothie, ingredients: milk, orange" %}

{% set items = [] %}

{% for item in product|split(',', 2) %}
    {% set tmp = item|split(':') %}
        
    {% set option = tmp[0] %}
    {% set values = [] %}
        
    {% for value in tmp[1]|split(',') %}
       {% set values = values|merge([ value, ]) %}
    {% endfor %}    
    
    {% set items = items|merge([ {'option': option, 'values': values,}, ]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dec59b)

---

As you've changed the initial input of the original question. The problem still starts with the `split` filter. I'd suggest you use another delimeter for your values, e.g. `;`

```html
{% set product = 'name: smoothie 3, ingredients: milk ; orange; pineapple, category: bar' %}
```

```html
{% set products = [] %}

{% for string in products_raw %}
    {% set product = [] %}
       
    {% for item in string|split(',') %}
        {% set tmp = item|split(':') %}
        
        {% set option = tmp[0] %}
        {% set values = [] %}
        
        {% for value in tmp[1]|split(';') %}
            {% set values = values|merge([ value, ]) %}
        {% endfor %}    
    
        {% set product = product|merge([ {'option': option, 'values': values,}, ]) %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% set products = products|merge([ product, ]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for product in products %}
    {% for item in product %}
    - Option: {{ item.option }}
    - Values:
    {% for value in item.values %}
        - {{value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}    
----------------------------------
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dec59b/2)

Comment: This does not work for the following string "name: smoothie, ingredients: milk, orange, cookie, category: vegan"...maybe i should specify that there could be numerous option-values pairs inside the string

Comment: That is because you've changed the input of your question. The problem still lays in the initial problem i've mentioned

Comment: the pattern of the input is option: value, option: value, value, value, option: value, value....
I thought it was obvious my bad....

Comment: Well you need to change the pattern of your input or it will never work. See my edit

Comment: Found a way to make it work without changing the pattern although i do understand that i should just communicate with someone who has the privilege to change the pattern. Thank you a lot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot for all the tips, i changed the logic a bit and it works now.
I will search about twig extensions as you proposed since it is for sure too much code in twig for something like that.

```
{% set product = "name: smoothie, ingredients: milk, orange, sugar, tags: healthy, popular, category: milk" %}
{% set options = [] %}
{% set last_option = null %}
{% set last_value = null %}
{% for item in product|split(',') %}
    {% set x = item|split(':') %}
    {% if x|length == 2 %}
        {% if last_value|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = options|merge( [ {option: last_option, value: last_value} ] ) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set last_option = x[0] %}
        {% set last_value = [x[1]] %}
    {% else %}
        {% set last_value = last_value|merge([x[0]]) %}
    {% endif%}
    {% if loop.last %}
        {% if last_value|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = options|merge( [ {option: last_option, value: last_value} ] ) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# print result #}
{% for item in options %}
    {{ item.option }}
    {% for inner_item in item.value %}
        {{ "-" ~ inner_item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```