# How to show a hierarchical list?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have one table in doctrine's entity:

| id | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | category1 | product_1 |
| 2 | category2 | product_2 |
| 3 | category1 | product_3 |
| 4 | category1 | product_4 |
| 5 | category2 | product_5 |
| 6 | category2 | product_6 |

I get in in my controller   `$products = $repository->findBy([],['id'=>'ASC']);`

and i want to show it in twig's template as:

- category1

  - product_1
  - product_3
  - product_4
- category2

  - product_2
  - product_5
  - product_6

I mean, I just want a hierarchy

I tried to use [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) and [column](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/column.html)

```
  {% for item in products %}
  {{ item.category }} 
    {% set product_items = products|column('name' is same as(item.category)) %}
      {% for ep in product_items %}
        {{ ep }}
      {% endfor %}   
  {% endfor %}
```

it doesn't work and seems to me that there is a simpler way to just show this hierarchy from one table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of sorting product by id, try sorting by category instead. Then as you cycle through in twig all products will be grouped by category. You may have to apply some logic in twig to display like you want, but this should be easy.

Comment: Merging/grouping items in twig is very "messy". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401743/reorganize-array-in-twig)

Comment: Create a domain object for Categories that can reverse it's relationship with Products, then you can `for category in categories` and within that loop `for product in category.products`. That will work better long-term than embedding logic directly in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You have many possibilities but i would recommend creating your own query instead of using a findBy :

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$db
    ->select('p')
    ->groupBy('p.category')
    ->orderBy('p.product_id', 'DESC');

$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```