# Change value of array element at specific index

Tags: twig

I want to change the value of array element at a specific position but whenever i am trying to so it throws me an error. Can anyone suggest me a way to change the value

```
{% set explode_field_id = data.field_id|split('-') %}       
{% set explode_field_id_length = explode_field_id|length %}
{% set reqValue = explode_field_id_length - 1 %}
{% set explode_field_id[reqValue] = data.field_details[dependent_field] %}
{% set dependent_field_id = explode_field_id|join('-') %}
```

Here explode_field_id = categoryList-category_list-0-category_list

ERROR - Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block" expected).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic multidimensional array in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461972/dynamic-multidimensional-array-in-twig)

Comment: [Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401743/reorganize-array-in-twig)

Comment: Not exactly. i dont know every single value i need are correct but whenever it comes to changing value at certain index it throws me an error. Is there any other way except the merge thing

Comment: Nope, there is not, well not with vanilla twig. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978499/set-value-of-single-object-in-multidimensional-array-in-twig-template) to solve this issue with a twig extension